# Adding back button to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a bottom navigation bar that contains 4 fragments and when a tab is selected a new instance of that fragment is loaded.

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.navigation_home:
            fragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_cards:
            fragment = CardsFragment.newInstance();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_deals:
            fragment = DealsFragment.newInstance();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_settings:
            fragment = SettingsFragment.newInstance();
            break;
    }
    if (fragment != null) {


        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    return true;
}
};
```

Now in my HomeFragment there is a RecyclerView that On Item Select it opens a new Fragment:

```
   myViewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            System.out.println("clicked");

            Fragment fragment = new TargetDetailsFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();





        });
```

I want to add a back button to the TargetDetails Fragments that takes you back to the home page when selected and I attempted doing that by implementing  OnBackStackChangedListener in the Main activity

```
@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    shouldDisplayHomeUp();
}

public void shouldDisplayHomeUp(){
    //Enable Up button only  if there are entries in the back stack
    boolean canback = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0;
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(canback);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    //This method is called when the up button is pressed. Just the pop back stack.
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    return true;
}
```

}

but the problem is when I click on it its reloads the HomeFragment Again but I simply want it to go back to the saved instance of that Fragment

Comment: Well, then use `add`instead of replace on the click method for `cardview`
And you could handle the back button in that fragment specifically (detach fragment and popbackstack)

Comment: Thank you for you response, when i did that it display over the homeFragment

Comment: Well, that is the point.. This way you have homeFragment behind current one (like a stack) and it won't get reloaded(homeFragment i mean)

Comment: Thanks Ionut but im having issues detaching the HomeFragment so when i click on the card the home fragment and the targets page are displayed on the same UI any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code that I have used for the `ViewPager`, the idea is to see if the current page number is 0 than to proceed `super.onBackPressed();` otherwise go to the previous fragment:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(vpPager.getCurrentItem()!=0) {
        vpPager.setCurrentItem(vpPager.getCurrentItem()-1, true);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for replying, i tried out your solution it sill ended up reloading the homeFragment again

Answer (score 0):

By adding below code in your Activity.
The fragment back stack can be managed.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        if (count == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            //additional code
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Vir, i actually only want the back behaviour on that particular fragment

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Bolu Okunaiya i think you should try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774432/navigating-to-previous-fragment-without-reloading-it) it will help you to manage backstack to desired fragment without loading same fragment again.

For Stop loading previous fragment you should use "add" instead of "replace" with your FragmentTransaction

Comment: Thanks ill check it out hopefully its helpful

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `MainActivity`

```
@Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            //shouldDisplayHomeUp();
            Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                              .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

          if (currentFragment instanceof TargetDetails) {
                  Log.v(TAG, "your current fragment is TargetDetails");
                  popBackStackImmediate(); //<<<< immediate parent fragment will open,which is your HomeFragement

                 }

        }
```

To use `popBackStackImmediate()` you need to *replace FragmentA with FragmentB and use `addToBackstack()` before `commit()`.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Radhey i tried your solution and i get this error java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions

Comment: google on this exception brother! it is common error, I can provide you line to line code but it will note increase your knowledge.

Comment: Thanks Bro ill do that and come back when i get a solution